# Order stacked Vega Lite bar graph by specific order

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following [VL chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIGdoBDAGwFNNtIAjI+AEwAUj77l5UBJeeMgJ0oAGAHQBmAL4AacLkgA3ZGQDulYAQAufWAGsyAeQAORaMnUBPIZKgALMmmvrKo0YKuQlyeuuuUArL8EpGTwAWyI+bVVIdVhYEnVkA0p4AFcSEiDcKCIAD2R8VWDZVD5PSkRSfDJpLLwSImoyEgBBDnJLIrqGpoAxBEcsSBCUqtgAWnw6fDGXQUga2sh6xpI++HUAZWQALwosAEZfBayl7tX+gHU7VAdKSHhYPjCSec6oBPVyNYGoYdGJqYzQRzY6yD5ffpbXaUQ6gvDgsjfK72H73R7PSBFcQyTJQehEdREKLwIghPZ4glE3FDcKRLBqcwGck0cKQakIwondRkHKogAiTWQcn4ZHoYHwKRCYT4FlBkDo0GsjzuIU89HacsQ-RVIzI40m8Gms1eJy16yh5IATK4ipBYIhEFUfjbTZdrrdBg8nqRMRBqWR4HA2BxObJHvR+FEUE16CqyJpkNB5u8zEy7g9VSSXrj4bF4olKABtN5qaMkWODADEYAAUrBqAU3IzmQBHFJ0D4EoUUHO4UuKctxhNJpup5kZ9g+7FZAC6crgJGV9Le0TH6dgmZ9cKgZYrv3jpRHK8IpHJanoG6I7CLkD08DACTJycgABkCRQ51A+HRUOTC5BK2tFwAA5LWfSt6AATl8UQABZEEgGdezqMhfwYUNaigZZem1QY-j1AFDSBEE3i6FZvgtGEjlI95THaLBUnSbc8HtR14w6TC8CMVh2HQLAXU4ggzBCag4gAFTXQYTD4aB2jeadcF7SAcgwsFJKgCcsxNRZdzufFuW0rlkDJABVeBTBVfprH0iht3lPICnpaI6PJRiMixOULGXTDVzTQY2w7Uwu2FQzZF0qta3rRsV1yfIo3RAk7gAP0bWjPjIAANSgxgCBS-RxBZIAAEkIWwwjuBx1AMfAMAAelq4VUCIYRUFMawUmoYRkFgWrSrIMIGtQogxhIUwyAa0RhFg4QRAAK3wBBtMgWwUScFxCqIFIYnwHYz188cEB7QruODPiqBiJIsHWrCyEQH59mBNxShue7HqgUT1BiEInECQqPC8HwsH8ATIH0ognUc7BbTBosS1B987mtfZILGfZ9jGS1IOfMlhzuO8H2M2yoGrOsG0oAB2ZCqBsxHBGR1H0ZcbGD0TPH70fImAMisn+Kp88EcGJGUf2S0xjp5nccGfGOfA7nIf2Pn4YMwW6eF0XBDAtwccPNmCafNwSaiygADZFZplX6ZFsXRAlnWpfZwnZdJyHTe3fnlagIXUfV2DbdZ+29c5w2ebASm3aV5kvatwRfD9pMA5lg25aEM2Bc91WGYxrGtZZ+OoDfAyk+dmFU49yAo8ZkF90l-OEaLo3efD8308t9X9jju4C6D5PG7h5vy4z6PNeru3a8L4me7AX6+7TgfW+tjvBi7p2G7ABWm9nqOfcXsfu+Lg5S8jwf1djnOa9fOuJ-3qe8rAGccRAcQgA) and I wish to specify that the ordering of the stacks match the order of the domain given.

I've had a look and I see some examples where ordering of nominal axes can be done by passing a list to sort, but I can't seem to find similar logic for colour stacks.

I understand how to order based on some quantitative variable, and clearly the ordering by 'metric' label here is just doing it alphabetically, but I would like to avoid having to add extra columns to the data if possible and just specify it in the VL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting stacked fields by a specific order (rather than according to a data field, as you've done in your example) is not supported in Vega-Lite. The relevant feature request is here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1734

A workaround is to use a calculate transform to encode the desired order. A simple example of this can be found here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/stack.html#order